# NSString isEqualToString: for \n

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, string-comparison

I have an Cocoa app that calls a web service.  When I parse the response from the web service I am getting a \n as the last character in my foundCharacters delegate for the NSXMLParser for each element in the XML.

When I try to do the following:

```
if (![string isEqualToString:@"\n"])
```

The check will always fails to catch the newline.  Anyone know a good way to string check a newline?

I also find it odd that each element would have a newline at the end of each value, even though I see no evidence of that in the output from the web service.

This is quite the problem for something that should be exceptionally easy to do.

Comment: I assume the above code was meant to be "isEqualToString:" rather than "isStringEqualTo:"?

Comment: Yes thank you, I've changed it in the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this is just what you need?
    text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Just out of curiosity, anyone know why this must be done? In almost every other language you wouldn't need to do this step, you could simply do a string comparison on a newline, or it an issue of how UNIX interprets the linefeed carriage return like jayw mentioned?

Comment: Scott Lance: Read my answer. It explains why his `isEqualToString:` message didn't work as he expected.

Answer (score 12):

> When I parse the response from the web service I am getting a \n as the last character …
>
> When I try to do the following:
>
> ```
> if (![string isEqualToString:@"\n"])
> ```
>
> The check will always fails to catch the newline.

That message will only return `YES` if `string` is one character long and that character is `\n`.

If you want to test whether a string *ends with* `\n`, then you need to use `hasSuffix:`:

```
if (![string hasSuffix:@"\n"])
```

If you want to *strip* `\n` from the end of the string and use what remains, phunehehe's solution is the correct one.

**Edit:** In Jeremy W. Sherman's answer, he points out the web service may be giving you CRLF-terminated text. This is a valid point, and you should not only look for `\n` at the end the line, but also check for a full `\r\n` sequence. The code he presents is one way to do that. However you do it, you still need to delete the full line separator, even if it's a `\r\n` sequence.

Answer (score 4):

The web service is likely terminating all lines with `CRLF`, i.e., `"\r\n"`. You're on a UNIX system, so the linefeed character `'\n'` is taken as the line separator; the carriage return `'\r'` is left as part of the previous line. When printed, it will have the same effect as `'\n'`. Have you verified (using, say, `strvis`) that the line-final character is `'\n'` and not `'\r'`?

`-[NSString hasSuffix:]` will only catch the specific newline character you provide. To test if the string ends in a newline or whitespace, here is a putative category method:

```
- (BOOL)my_hasWhitespaceOrNewlineSuffix {
  NSRange r = [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]
                                    options:NSBackwardsSearch];
  BOOL foundChar = r.location != NSNotFound;
  BOOL isLineFinal = foundChar && (r.location + r.length == [self length]);
  return isLineFinal;
}
```

You can use phunehehe's suggestion of `text = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]` to remove any line-final whitespace or newlines.